# When is a complex surface not symplectic

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is there an invariant in terms of Euler characteristic $e$ and signature $\sigma$, that tells us a given complex surface is not symplectic.
Some related results are-
Complex surface is Kahler iff $b_{1}$ is even.
A four manifold admits an almost complex structure then $e+\sigma=0\mod4$.
Complex surfaces of general type are Kahler.
If a four manifold admits a Lefschetz fibration then it is symplectic.
But none of these help with my question.

Comment: Kähler surfaces are symplectic, and the only symplectic non-Kähler surfaces are primary Kodaira surfaces and their blowups. I don't think these surfaces can be characterised using the Euler characteristic and signature alone. However, they can be characterised in terms of $b_1$.